# Getting response from Using dataType script with jQuery on ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Not sure if this should work but from a jquery ajax request with the response I want to evaluate the script being passed back. Here goes for an example.

```
$.ajax({
    url: some/path,
    dataType: 'script'
});
```

Then with my response I'm using php to spit out the javascript.

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/javascript");

$str = <<<EOF
    alert('help');
EOF;
echo $str;
```

If I'm correct I should get a alert pop-up after performing the request.

I can see from the response headers it correct:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

And response is:

```
alert('help');
```

But no alert box is being triggered. Am I missing something or can this not be done this way?

Hope you can advise.

TY

Answer (score 1):

You should call success function in $.ajax

and execute the response

page1.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

  $.ajax({

      url: "page2.php",

      dataType: 'script',

      success: function(resp) {

          resp;  //this is your response which is contains alert('help')

      }

    });

</script>
```

page2.php

```
<?php

header("content-type: application/javascript");

$str = <<<EOF
    alert('help');
EOF;

echo $str;

?>
```

Comment: @Lee: May I know your feedback

Comment: I tried with success which I thought also was not necessary. but didn't work either.

Comment: I worked it out. I was using fileupload plugin which works a little strange. all good and my code works.